# Resize row's height table dynamically by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I found a way to resize the column dynamically by Javascript :
http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable.html

Does someone know a way to do same for the row?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, you should be more specific about the type of solution you want for your project.  The type of solution you want would depend on if you wanted dynamic nodes on each row or only allow row height change by clicking and dragging from a certain point.

Comment: If you want it to be like the demo it would be hard for the style of table in the example.  The example works well because they use resize by column header.  Their is no reason you could reuse the same script but for row headings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [jQuery UI's re-sizable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)? jQuery comes with a huge amount of other (presumably extraneous) functionality but this is a reliable and easy plugin to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already knew this plugin but it doesn't fit to my case.